# How to read compressed avro files (.gz) in spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, gzip

I am trying to read a gzip (.gz extension) avro file using spark but I am getting below error. I see from the documentation that spark should be able to read .gz files without any additional conversions (might be for csv/text files).

I tried running below command but it gives error:

```
df= spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/user/data/test1.avro.gz")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 149, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.load.
: java.io.IOException: Not an Avro data file
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader.openReader(DataFileReader.java:63)
        at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$$anonfun$5.apply(DefaultSource.scala:80)
        at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$$anonfun$5.apply(DefaultSource.scala:77)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource.inferSchema(DefaultSource.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:184)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:184)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:387)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:135)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2):

Compression in an avro file works by separately compressing the individual data blocks, the avro file itself is not compressed ([docs](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Object+Container+Files)). ORC and Parquet compression works in a similar way, this is how these formats can be splittable.

In other words, you can't run `gzip` on an uncompressed .avro file and read it directly, the way you can with plain text files.

Compression happens when you write the avro file, in spark this is controlled by either the `spark.sql.avro.compression.codec` SparkConf setting, or the compression option on the writer ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#data-source-option)).

Comment: could you please add relevant links to the spark/avro documentation to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @smaug updated. The relevant part of the Avro spec is where it says "Objects are stored in blocks that may be compressed".